# Why use respective interfaces instead of concrete classes?

Tags: java

For example , why should I use

```
 Map<String, List<String>> phoneNumbers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

instead of

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> phoneNumbers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Comment: if phoneNumbers variable's scope is not greater than one method then I would say that usually there's no difference. If this is a field and you decide should your accessor use an interface or a concrete implementation then it really matters.

Comment: I agree with Sergey .. interfaces allow clean separation at *boundaries*, but are not necessarily applicable at a local (or private/protected) level.